# What is the most efficient way of setting variables in another class using C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am polling the event queue and setting variables in another class depending on the event result.

```
while(!fin){
  pollEvents();
}
```

And in the event handler:

```
case Sdl.SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
  game.setdx(e.motion.y);
  game.setdy(e.motion.x);
  break;
```

I am new to C# from Java. My understanding is that these values will be passed by value rather than reference and am wondering if it would be better to:

1. make dx and dy in the other class public and simply set the values
2. use pointers to dx and dy and set the values using them

Comment: With the code you've supplied, we can't tell whether the arguments will be passed by reference or by value - that will depend on the variable type.  (but either way, that doesn't really matter)  You probably want to phrase your question more along the lines of "What is the best way" rather than "what is the most efficient way" - not many people really need the most efficient way, as for such a simple operation as providing a couple of variables to an object, that's the compiler's job to optimize that - you should probably worry more about what's the easiest to read/maintain :)

Comment: My understanding is that the variables will be passed by value unless the ref keyword is appended. The problem fundamentally, is that Java turns getter/setter methods into direct assignments that do not use the function stack. If C# uses the function stack, copying and popping variables passed whether references or primitives, then bypassing getter and setter methods would seem to be warranted. Also, when you consider that the game loop is running as fast as it can, and polling the events every cycle, it is not a simple operation to do with a couple of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out so thought i'd share. Properties are applicable to both classes and structures... I was under the impression they were solely for structures. Anyway, from what I understand, properties are like direct assignments. Syntax:

```
class ThatWillStoreTheVal{
  private bool ford=false;

  //seter/getter method called a property
  public bool fordP{
    set{ford=value;}
    get{return ford;}
  }
}

class ThatSetsTheProperty{
  private ThatWillStoreTheVal ob;

  //the assignment. Note that the method like name is called not the variable name
  ...
    if(e.key.keysym.sym==Sdl.SDLK_e) ob.fordP=true;
  ...
```

Comment: Stephen, since you're using C# v4, you can use the keystroke saving: public bool fordP { get; set; }